# How to disable build-in javascript/typescript suggestions in Monaco-Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to disable build-in javascript/typescript suggestions in Monaco-Editor, because I want to use language server suggestions instead.

Are there any option to disable build-in javascript/typescript suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use this

```
const myDiv: HTMLDivElement = this.editorContent.nativeElement;
const editorJS: ICodeEditor = editor.create(myDiv, {
      language: 'javascript',
      suggest: {
        showFields: false,
        showFunctions: false
      }
});
```

See all options at `ISuggestOptions` interface